# "Rust WASM toolchain not installed" with v0.9.25

Tags: rust, wasm, build, compilation

I recently [upgraded a fork of the Node Template to v0.9.25](https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/commit/d2e6ccc8e60dd0e259c33694e7eac9cc72e3331a) and now I am getting an [error about the Wasm toolchain not being installed](https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/runs/7308258170?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:1182). Per the official Substrate documentation, the failing build is [adding the Wasm target to the nightly toolchain](https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/blob/dfo/gssmr-test/.github/workflows/build-specs.yml#L35).

```
~: rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/werq/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.62.0 (a8314ef7d 2022-06-27)
```

Comment: Something amiss with your setup...? https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/runs/7203511144?check_suite_focus=true for sure this built with the template for this version

Comment: My setup has not changed - only the Substrate version changed and the build started failing. You can actually check out the set-up yourself by looking at the workflow configuration. I noticed that your build was passing, but I also noticed that it looks like that build is skipping Wasm compilation, which seems to be the root of my problem.

Comment: You probably dont want to build the runtime in the CI anyway? Then you can skip it with an env flag like for example [here](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-node/blob/f0a29200bed5d2e4ec6fcb0ce8ae121f9124ff5a/.github/workflows/rust.yml#L10).

Comment: I have the same problem when I build locally and I definitely need the runtime ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a transient problem that was fixed by updating my nightly version after a few days.